# Nested functions in python: Polynomial exercise

Tags: python, function

Context: I'm trying to make make a function that will return the value of any given polynomial. So for polynomial(a), where a = [a0,a1,...,an] should return a function p so that p(x) is the polynomial a0*x**n + a1*x**(n-1)...+an.

This is what I have:

```
def polynomial(coefs):
    
    def p(x):
        res = 0
        i = len(coefs)
        for a in coefs[:-1]:
            i -=1
            res += a*x**i
        res += coefs[-1]
        return res
    return p(x)
        
# Tests:
xx = [0, 1, 2, 3]   # Valores de x a testar
r = polynomial([1, 2, 3])   
print([r(x) for x in xx])   # should return [3, 6, 11, 18]
```

But I keep getting `name 'x' is not defined`. If I'm saving the polynomial function as `r`, then if we pass an argument such as r(2) shouldn't it basically return p(2) which will in turn return the result?

Thank you in advance! Any help is welcome as I'm still learning python

Note: I'm aware the function isn't perfect yet for the example I'm trying to achieve, but I'd simply like to retrieve the desired output first and then I'll check the inner workings of the p(x) function again

Comment: You should just return the function: `return p`, which you can then call with various values of `x`. i.e. `polynomial([1, 2, 3])(1)` which returns `6`.

Comment: @Mark Thank you so much, Mark! For some reason I got stuck in my head that the return should always have the argument as well. Much appreciated! And I apologize in advanced if the question seemed too easy, but I had no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can simplify this using lambda expression, and end up with something like this

```
from typing import List, Callable


def polynomials(coefs: List[int]) -> Callable[[int], int]:
    return lambda x: sum([coefs[len(coefs) - i - 1] * (x ** i) for i in range(len(coefs) - 1, -1, -1)])


function = polynomials([1, 2, 3])  # x^2 + 2x + 3

print(function(1))  # 6
print(function(2))  # 11
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try that out as well :)